# Laravel escape character in query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I'm coding a query :

```
$result = \DB::table('order_items as oi')
        ->selectRaw(
            'order_item_type as item_type,
            order_item_id as item_id,
            if(order_item_type = "App\\\Models\\\Book", oi.price, invoices.price) as price
              )
```

just note to `if` statement, I'm having to use **two** escape character or query doesnt match `App\Models\Book`. when i inspect output query by laravel debugger its :

```
select order_item_type as item_type,
order_item_id as item_id,
if(order_item_type = "App\\Models\\Book", oi.price, invoices.price) as price,...
```

whats happen here? does laravel query builder remove one slash and then mysql engine remove the second slash in run time ?

EDIT :
But somewhere else in the same query i have a `where` clause that i used **one**  escape character and it works fine:

```
 ->leftjoin('books', function ($q) {
            $q->on('q3.order_item_id', '=', 'books.id')
                ->where('q3.order_item_type', '=', 'App\\Models\\Book');
        })
```

and the output query part by laravel debugger:

```
left join `books` on `q3`.`order_item_id` = `books`.`id` and 
`q3`.`order_item_type` = 'App\Models\Book'
```

Can anyone explain why in `if` i must use **two** escape character but in `join` only **one** escape character is needed?
*in fact there would be no problem if i even don't use any escape character in `where` query builder method* and write the code as:

```
  ->leftjoin('books', function ($q) {
            $q->on('q3.order_item_id', '=', 'books.id')
                ->where('q3.order_item_type', '=', 'App\Models\Book');
        })
```

Comment: Have you tried to use either 4 or 2 backslashes? 3 backslashes look incorrect for me.

Comment: @IvanYarych this behavior is not the same all the time ,take a look at the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both PHP[<sup>1</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and MySQL[<sup>2</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) escapes slashes. MySQL on other hand requires them escaped unless `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`[<sup>3</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode is enabled - it's disabled by default. Within MySQL the escape sequence is either interpreted or ignored - `\n` will be translated into a new line, `\m` is ignored and translated into `m`.

So first PHP will convert `\\\` into `\\` - two get escaped into one. Then MySQL will also escape `\\` into `\`, understanding that you wanted a literal slash. :)

Regarding your edit, `selectRaw()` sends raw queries to MySQL, so you've to escape the data yourself. All other non-raw methods do this internally within Laravel Query Builder, so you don't have to bother with these things.

PHP, unlike MySQL, does not ignore slashes. Using single-quoted strings any non-ending slash will be recognized as literal anyway, so you are not required to escape them - if your string ends with a slash then you are required. With double-quoted strings there are escape sequences that gets translated - your example would still work with them, but there are cases that can go wrong.

Comment: thanks, i added an edit. would you please check the question again

Comment: I updated my answer to also answer your new question. ;)

Comment: I've not used any escape character in internal `where` query builder method,and it  works fine. does it mean `where` method will assume all user(developer) written characters as literal?

Comment: PHP, unlike MySQL, does not ignore slashes. Using single-quoted strings any non-ending slash will be recognized as literal anyway, so you are not required to escape them - if your string ends with a slash then you are required. With double-quoted strings there are escape sequences that gets translated - your example would still work with them, but there are cases that can go wrong. ;)